# If the DB connection fails, how can I tell PHP to pause a second and try again?

Tags: php, mysql

Every once in awhile, for about a second or two, my PHP script fails to authenticate and create a connection to MySQL server. Is there any way to tell PHP to, upon failure to create a MySQL connection, wait another second or two and then try again?

Do I need to limit the number of re-tries, or will the PHP script automatically quit after the HTTP connection is closed?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how does the tag [jquery] relate to this?

Comment: My jQuery script polls the server every few seconds. If the script fails to connect, it thinks the chat has ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With something like this:

```
<?php
$maxret = 10;
$db = false;
do
{
  $db = mysql_connect(....);
  if ($db !== false) break;

  sleep(2);
}while($maxret-- > 0);

if ($db === false){
   //Handle db error here. For instance you can redirect the browser to a courtesy page
   header("Location:/dbdown.php");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! What does --> mean? Does that increment $maxret?

Comment: It's literally `( $maxret -- ) > 0`.

Comment: Is there any way to keep an error long from being created whenever it fails? It seems like when it fails, execution just stops.

Comment: this just decrease the $maxret value by one on every iteration and check if the `while` condition is satisfied (greater than zero). I have added some spaces.

Comment: @Francesco : It will compare the condition , then decrease then value of $maxret.

Comment: @Gaurav yes! you are right! Otherwise it should be `while (--$maxret > 0)`